# Pairwise product of Pauli Matrices using Levi-Civita

Tags: linear-algebra, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Just a quick question. The professor used $$ \sigma_i \sigma_j = i \sum_k \epsilon_{ijk} \sigma_k$$

to define products of Pauli matrices. This works fine to get $$\sigma_x \sigma_y = i \sigma_z$$ and the other cyclic products.

Though what is tripping me up is that we know $$\sigma_x^2 = \sigma_y^2 = \sigma_z^2 = \mathbb{I}.$$
However, if I look at it from the summation defined above the $$\sigma_x^2 = \sigma_x \sigma_x = i \sum_k \epsilon_{xxk}\sigma_k = 0.$$

Since $\forall k$ $\epsilon_{ijk} = 0$ if $i=j=x$ based on the definition of Levi-Civita.

For a bit of context, we haven't "defined" the matrices explicitly in their matrix form so the basic definition to be used is the summation one instead of explicit matrix products for each pair of matrices. In this sense, I the definition would give me 0 for the squares, but clearly that is not the case.

From this perspective, I feel like there is a very subtle simple bit that I am missing. Is it the definition or the summation or something else?

Comment: Why don't you ask your professor? This seems like a non-standard definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you correctly noticed, the relation
$$\sigma_i \sigma_j = i \sum_k \epsilon_{ijk} \sigma_k$$
is true only for $i\ne j$, but it is wrong for $i=j$.

The correct relation holding for all $ij$ combinations is
(see also [Pauli matrices - Relation to dot and cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Relation_to_dot_and_cross_product)):
$$\sigma_i \sigma_j = \delta_{ij} \mathbb{I} + i\sum_k \epsilon_{ijk} \sigma_k$$

For the special cases of $i=j$ this relation correctly reduces to
$$\sigma_x^2 = \sigma_y^2 = \sigma_z^2 = \mathbb{I}$$

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense, the prof must've missed this case. Will raise it with him.